# .net xml serialization

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I used the xsd utility to generate a *.cs file from an *.xsd file.  I'd like to generate xml from this generated class by serializing an instance of the class.  Is there any way to get 'clean' output like this:

```
<header>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</header>
```

Here are two examples of the not clean output I am getting:

```
<header>
  <br xsi:type="xsd:string" />
  <br xsi:type="xsd:string" />
  <br xsi:type="xsd:string" />
  <br xsi:type="xsd:string" />
</header>

<header>
  <br xsi:nil="true" />
  <br xsi:nil="true" />
  <br xsi:nil="true" />
  <br xsi:nil="true" />
</header>
```

Running this code to create the object being serialized:

```
KioskSchema.applicationScreens screenContainer = new KioskSchema.applicationScreens();
//screenContainer.header = new object[] { null, null, null, null };                                     //didn’t work
//screenContainer.header = new string[] { "<br/>", "<br/>", "<br/>", "<br/>"};               //didn’t work
screenContainer.header = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty };       //didn’t work
```

Here is the class generated from the xsd utility

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class applicationScreens
{

       private object[] headerField;

       private applicationScreensScreen[] screenField;

       /// <remarks/>
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("br", IsNullable = false)]
       public object[] header
       {
              get
              {
                     return this.headerField;
              }
              set
              {
                     this.headerField = value;
              }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a namespace is being added when you don't want it to.

Change the XmlArrayItemAttribute in the generated .cs file - add Namespace = null or Namespace = string.Empty:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("br", IsNullable = false, Namespace = string.Empty)]
```

That should override the default namespace that is being added.

Read more about [XmlArrayItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The xsd utility set the type of the header propery and it's private member varible to object[].  Manually changing them to string[] fixed the problem!

```
public partial class applicationScreens
{

    private string[] headerField;

    private applicationScreensScreen[] screenField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("br", Namespace="",  IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }
```

Actual output:

```
<header>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</header>
```